# amp-ad not working correctly in combination with amp-fx-flying-carpet

Tags: amp-html

i am currently not able to add an `amp-ad` tag inside of a `amp-fx-flying-carpet` tag. The `flying-carpet` container will be rendered correctly but the containing `amp-ad` tag is apparently not processed at all.

Strangely, the `amp-ad` tag is properly rendered when I place the exact same `amp-fx-flying-carpet` tag a second (or third) time on the page.

Does someone have the same problem?

[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsbin.com/womakiluji/edit?html,console,output)
(You have to scroll down the output frame)

Comment: Doc for the flying-carpet extension: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-fx-flying-carpet/

Comment: I had the same problem. Since the 2nd/3rd Dec, the Flying Carpet no longer shows Adsense ads and exchanged them. The week from Release to this date was fine.
My suspicion was that it against the Adsene Police was the display partly to cover.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue on github https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6735

It seems that the developer has fixed something and i hope it will be released soon.